# Saving multiple clicks with jQuery instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my `jQuery` function. I have a form which saves some values. I have clickable elements called "points" in which users can state how important that question is. Each question has this clickable element, but the problem is that users only can choose 1 clickable element...

If I click on another element, it does light up and adds the class "extra-important" to it, but it does not save it. When I click on save, it only has saved the *first clicked* question, instead of them all. **What I want is: it should save them all.**

What am I doing wrong? This is the snippet..

```
function change_importance_question (e) {
    var t = jQuery("#" + e).closest("form"),
        n = e.substring(e.indexOf("_") + 1),
        n = n.substring(0, n.indexOf("_"));
    jQuery("input[name*='_question']", t).val(n);
    jQuery("#" + e).removeClass("not-important").addClass("extra-important")
}
```

Can someone explain how I can get them to save every one of them (when clicked)? Do I have to use `preventdefault`?

Comment: Can you please share a test fiddle ? http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: No, I can't... But I would love to give you a test account on the website. Is that okay? Privately?

Comment: @ Siyah I would have liked to help. But, looks like I have to go to have lunch (2:00 pm here). I have bookmarked this question to have a look later :)

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate that. Have a nice meal!

Comment: Can you add some comments to the code so that we can see what you expect your variables to be. Also, look up how to debug with chrome developer tools (Inspect element > sources > select JS file > add a break point > initiate function) as this will help you shed light on where the code is going wrong. Note that a breakpoint has to be put inside a callback function, e.g. .click(function () {//callback}) otherwise the debugger will look like it has jumped over the function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the value of 't' and 'n' to make sure its not the same each time or undefined?

```
function change_importance_question (e) {
    // when I run this code with e is the event i get 
    // Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]
    var t = jQuery("#" + e).closest("form");
    console.log(t)
    var n = e.substring(e.indexOf("_") + 1);
    console.log(n);
    n = n.substring(0, n.indexOf("_"));
    console.log(n)
    // if t is undefined it will find and set all input elements named _question on the entire page
    jQuery("input[name*='_question']", t).val(n);
    jQuery("#" + e).removeClass("not-important").addClass("extra-important")
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Still the same brother, only saving the last clicked one.

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle to demonstrate what your doing because I can't see how you're getting a dom element by doing var t = jQuery("#" + e).closest("form"); Unless e is a string with an element ID not an event object?

Comment: If this code is setting the right values on the right elements perhaps its not the cause of your problem. Im not sure what you mean by 'saving'?